# Issue with Xcode Target and settings for Apple Watch App

Tags: ios, xcode, settings, watchos

I am running into an issue where I have tested my Apple Watch app on many simulators in Xcode and on my personal devices, but when I submitted to Apple for review, they are telling me that it will not run and to check my plist folder. I cannot find my plist folder as I accidentally removed it, which led me to the settings possibly being the issue. The app is set to be run only on the watch without a companion app.

Inserting pictures of my settings.

[image]

[image: more settings]

[image]

I have tried adjusting the settings to only have the watch shown in supported devices as well as just iOS and that gave me an error saying that I could not build for a simulator for a watch only app.

Comment: **Please don't post code, error or other data as image.** Please [edit] your question and post as text instead. You can use the image as an *addition* if it really contains information that you can't describe otherwise. See also: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)